# Is there a way to determine progress on a disk check at boot?

Tags: 10.04, server, boot, disk, lts

During the boot process, a disk check can be run, but during this process there is no indication or detailed information available to gauge how far along the process is.

Is there a way to display any information that would indicate how far along it is?

This is more a problem for server environments, rather then desktop environments.  Looking for information around 10.04 LTS.

Answer (score 1):

Not really - the amount of time left is a function of how many problems are on the part of the filesystem that hasn't yet been checked. See `man fsck`

From `man fsck`:

```
   -C [  fd  ]
          Display  completion/progress  bars for those filesystem checkers (currently only for ext2 and
          ext3) which support them.   Fsck will manage the filesystem checkers so that only one of them
          will  display  a progress bar at a time.  GUI front-ends may specify a file descriptor fd, in
          which case the progress bar information will be sent to that file descriptor.
```

Comment: Even a progress indicator on what inode/file or block out of the total the scan is on would be useful, but it sounds like nothing like that is provided.